# Bloom and transparency

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I know bloom is supposed to render with transparency as of 2.91, and it is showing in my render. I'd like to put my rendered graphics into obs, and as soon as I open it there, the bloom disappears. I've opened it in video editing software too. No luck.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!